# Simple java program gets RC=2009 connecting to remote Queue Manager

Tags: ibm-mq

I am writing a simple java program to connect to remote WebSphere MQ Queue Manager but its showing the error: `MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2009'`

Yet when I connect using WMQ Explorer, its getting connected and I am able to see the messages in the queue there. Kindly help.  My code is:

```
        public void init(){

     props.put(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "sailmq3d.pok.ibm.com");
     props.put(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "PLM.SECURE.SVRCONN");
     props.put(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1423); // port number
     props.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);
     }

       public void start(){
   try {
  // Create a connection to the queue manager
qMgr = new MQQueueManager("PLMESB_SBMD2",props);
```

Comment: What does the channel definition for PLM.SECURE.SVRCONN look like?  Does "secure" mean it is SSL-enabled?  Is it the same channel that WMQ Explorer uses?

Comment: @Rob: can u please help what is going wrong here

Comment: its the simple connection used to connect to remote MQ Queue Manager and with the same channel i am able to connect in MQExplorer

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this is kinda cool - for once I can actually *see* the QMgr from the SO posted question!

The `PLM.SECURE.SVRCONN` channel definition looks like this:

```
AMQ8414: Display Channel details.
   CHANNEL(PLM.SECURE.SVRCONN)             CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
   ALTDATE(2011-01-30)                     ALTTIME(15.02.56)
   COMPHDR(NONE)                           COMPMSG(NONE)
   DESCR( )                                HBINT(300)
   KAINT(AUTO)                             MAXINST(999999999)
   MAXINSTC(999999999)                     MAXMSGL(4194304)
   MCAUSER(nobody)                         MONCHL(QMGR)
   RCVDATA( )                              RCVEXIT( )
   SCYDATA( )
   SCYEXIT(/var/mqm/exits64/PLMESB_SBMD2/ESBSecurityExit(ChannelExit))
   SENDDATA( )                             SENDEXIT( )
   SHARECNV(10)                            SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)
   SSLCIPH( )                              SSLPEER( )
   TRPTYPE(TCP)
```

Given that there is a custom security exit on that channel, it's not possible to say why you receive a 2009 return code.  Probably the best bet is to look at the security exit logs.

The connection through WMQ Explorer is probably using `SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN` which has no exit.

I see that there is also a CLNTCONN defined for that channel and it requires a client-side exit.  If your Java client uses a Client Conn Definition Table (CCDT) then this would further complicate matters.  The fact that the CLNTCONN exists and lists a client-side exit suggests that `PLM.SECURE.SVRCONN` won't work without that client-side exit.

Comment: @Rob: Can you please provide the code for MQ Security Exit which i can use to run the present program and get it connected to Queue Manager....

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob...Finally understood the problem.. If I am not wrong i think i need to write the MQ Security Exit program which will authenticate my userid and mac address to the server. I need to set this in my java program..

Comment: Well, it looks like someone already wrote that since it is specified in the CLNTCONN channel.  Check with your WMQ admin to see if they know where to get it.  Whatever the client side module is must work as a pair with the channel's `ESBSecurityExit`, which already exists. Someone is using it successfully, I can see it running.

Comment: Actually while browsing the queue and retrieving the messages , once the queue becomes empty, it shows the following error MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2033.....which means no more messages are available in the queue which is natural. Is there any way to suppress this warning or to resolve this..Presently i am using MQException.logExclude(new Integer(MQException.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE)); to suppress this warning...Please help

Comment: Post as a new question.  SO doesn't work well as a conversational forum because secondary and tertiary Q&A doesn't get indexed. I'm at IMPACT this week and have an 18-hour day tomorrow so to get you started, look at adding FAIL_IF_QUIESCING and do the GET with an unlimited WAIT. Even if you figure it out based on this, please post a new question so we can record the answer for other people to find. Thanks!